# Executing angular services in some other scope?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope, socket.io, angular-services

I am designing a RealTime system using `Angular` and `Socket.IO`.

I am using two different factory one for Subscribing to the topic and other for writing logic for its callback function and subscribing it there.

> pubsub.js

```
app.factory('PubSub', function(){
   return{
     subscribe: function(event, callback){ 
        socket.on(event, callback);
      }, //end subscribe
   }
})
```

> orders.js

```
app.factory('Orders', function(PubSub){
   return{
      subscribeOrderUpdate : function(){
        //Subscribing 
        PubSub.subscribe('onUpdateOrder', this.onOrderUpdate);
      },

      //Callback function
      onOrderUpdate: function(order){
        var result = this.findOrder(order.Id);
        console.log('Order has been updated');
      },

      findOrder(OrderId){
         //logic to find order based on orderId
      }

   };
});
```

Now when I am calling this from my controller

```
//Controller..
app.controller('OrdersPage', function($scope, Orders){
   Orders.subscribeOrderUpdate(); 
   /* Shows Error this.findOrder() is not a function*/
});
```

Now when I am calling this factory its displaying error that `this.findOrder` is not a function.

After searching I found out that since my callback function `onOrderUpdate` 
is getting called in `PubSub` factory scope thus its showing error because `this.findOrder` is defined in  `Orders` factory scope.

So how should I define it so that `this.findOrder` gets called in its right scope.

Comment: Did you try to define it as function? `findOrder: function (OrderId)`

Comment: No, because I need to define it inside factory because there are other logic defiend in findOrder which needs to be inside Orders factory scope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try re-factoring your Orders service to something like..

```
app.factory('Orders', function(PubSub){

  var service = {
    subscribeOrderUpdate  : subscribeOrderUpdate
  };

  return service;
  //////////////////////////////

  function subscribeOrderUpdate(){
    //Subscribing 
    PubSub.subscribe('onUpdateOrder', onOrderUpdate);
  }

  function onOrderUpdate(order){
    var result = findOrder(order.Id);
    console.log('Order has been updated');
  }

  function findOrder(OrderId){
     //logic to find order based on orderId
  }

});
```

If you need to use your `findOrder` method directly anywhere else you can expose it just like the `subscribeOrderUpdate` method but it doesn't look like you need to so I removed it along with the `onOrderUpdate`. Best to only expose what you need.

Comment: Its working now. Its a better way for scope resolution in javascript will never forget it now.